# Embed submodule dependencies for proprietary code

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I'm working on an Android library. This library use **other local libraries**/modules. But these **sub-modules are not published** in anyway to a public repository. I'm searching ways to **embed these proprietary submodule in the main library**.

I've already found some ways, like building a **fat aar but this is not a good practice at all**. I was wondering if someone know a good way to do this.

**EDIT**:
I've made a simple script that before the build of the main library, `assemble` the sub modules and copy the output `aar` to a new modules which is the one generated by Android Studio. The script works but Android didn't add this empty modules aar in the main library when creating the aar.